# Setting up NGINX as reverse proxy for multiple containerized services

Tags: nginx, devops, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I developed a web app with vue and django however, I'm having problems deploying it.
I added another container to serve as reverse proxy so only port 80 would be exposed and when I finish struggling with this also port 443. I could not find exact anwser how to do it so I hope someone here will be kind enoug to give me some clues.

Here is the conf for the nginx.
The error I'm getting is on ui container.
2022/07/14 09:09:00 [emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)

I looked it up of course, but it was always some different scenario.

BR and thanks in advance

```
server {
    listen  0.0.0.0:80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
                    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
    }
    location /predict {
                    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/predict;
    }
    location /aggregate {
                    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/aggregate;
    }
    location /media/pictures {
                    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/media/pictures;
    }

    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/anomaly_access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/anomaly_error.log;
}
```

My docker-compose looks as follows.

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    se-kpi-sim:
        image: test-app:0.0.1
        network_mode: "host"
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MODEL_NAME: "model_final.pickle.dat"

    se-kpi-sim-ui:
        image: test-ui:0.0.3
        network_mode: "host"
        restart: unless-stopped

    reverse-proxy:
        image: test-proxy:0.0.7
        network_mode: "host"
        restart: unless-stopped

    database:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_USER: kpi_sim_user
            POSTGRES_DB: kpi_sim
            POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
    database:
```

Comment: Du you have a docker-compose or some other .yml file defining the network?

Comment: thanks for the interest. These are my first steps in docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run containers on docker internal network and `docker-compose` by default creates an network for inter communication of containers. One can modify the port to expose the application to host. while you are trying to run most of the app on host network, there might be two application trying to use the same port (like port `8080` [in this case]), one port can only be used by one application in an OS . Please look at the below snippet for more information to solve this issue.

[port mapping `<port on HOST>:<container port where app is exposed inside container>`]

```
version: '3.2'
services:
    se-kpi-sim:
        image: test-app:0.0.1
        ports:
          - 5000:8080
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MODEL_NAME: "model_final.pickle.dat"

    se-kpi-sim-ui:
        image: test-ui:0.0.3
        ports:
          - 3000:8080
        restart: unless-stopped

    reverse-proxy:
        image: test-proxy:0.0.7
        ports:
          - 80:80
        # this volume mount if you are using bitnami/nginx image
        volumes:
          - /path/to/my_server_block.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf:ro

        restart: unless-stopped

    database:
        image: postgres
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_USER: kpi_sim_user
            POSTGRES_DB: kpi_sim
            POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
    database:
```

One have to specify either the IP address or DNS name of the application , in order to forward the traffic to specific application. `docker-compose` create Domain name for all the services defined in `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
server {
    listen  0.0.0.0:80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
                    proxy_pass http://se-kpi-sim-ui:8080;
    }
    location /predict {
                    proxy_pass http://se-kpi-sim:8080/predict;
    }
    location /aggregate {
                    proxy_pass http://se-kpi-sim:8080/aggregate;
    }
    location /media/pictures {
                    proxy_pass http://se-kpi-sim:8080/media/pictures;
    }

    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/anomaly_access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/anomaly_error.log;
}
```

One can mount the `nginx.conf` like:[in `bitnami/nginx` image]

```
...
volumes:
      - /path/to/my_server_block.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf:ro
...
```

Note: all the above is an example for reference to solve the problem. `entrypoint` for containers might change according to one's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate this, however, it still doesn't work. What concerns me is where to copy the proxy.conf file in the image in Dockerfile for proxy. In my Vue file, it is:
COPY nginx/development.conf /opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks
I think in proxy it must be different dir.
Other thing is rather silly. All the vue calls to backend must still be localhost:8080 or docker somehow will know that it is se-kpi-sim:8080?

Comment: updated the answer for the mount location for `nginx.conf`, all the backend call will happen at `se-kpi-sim:8080` according to the your configs (or to be specific at the container IP of se-kpi-sim) [`se-kpi-sim` is just an DNS name mapped to container IP]. Please be sure to add allowed host in django and host it on 0.0.0.0 to accept traffic from any IP.

Comment: OK I got it partially working, My redirects are hitting the django endpoints however, the payload is not redirected so I get 500 error. Would you know how to fix it pls

Comment: I finally got it working. In axios you actully give only hostname of your site no ports the redirects will work. For some reason backend did not work on port 8080 so i changed it to 5000. Also added some directives to location to accept aplication/json. Thanks to you I learned how docker networking works. Good job